# From where does .gitignore have effect?

Tags: git, push, gitignore

(Very new to git!)

The .gitignore indications have effect because

the gitignore file is saved locally and it prevents the push of some special files

or

because the gitignore file is already commited/placed on server and from there it says that certain files are not allowed on the'central repository'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git looks to local version of .gitignore file to determine what to ignore. It, however, doesn't prevent you from committing ignored files. Rather, it makes committing such files harder (thus avoiding many, many mistakes).

However, .gitignore is usually placed to the repository itself, so that you don't need to write it from scratch every time you clone.

To sum up,

- .gitignore on remote repository does nothing;
- local .gitignore protects you from committing garbage files to you local repo and consequently polluting remote repo by pushing that garbage to it.

Comment: To be more precise, .gitignore only has affect in one situation: when a file is not tracked. It has two effects: 1. git status won't show you the file. 2. git add prevents you from adding it unless you provide -f.

Comment: And to pick a further nit: If the `.gitignore` file is under git's care or not is irrelevant. Besides, you can have several, one in each directory, git looks in the one in the current directory, then it's parent, up to the repository root.

Answer (score 2):

None of them, `.gitignore` file prevent you for committing certain files in your **local** repository.

This is a side effect of no pushing `.gitignore` files to the server, as you will never have those files commited in your local repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! (Apologize,ingrate situation: I gave the 'green tick to shakurov since he has less points)

Comment: @Roxana Pleased to help =)